# Given $\{A_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}=\{\{0\},\{0,1\},...,\{0,1,2,…\}\}$, is $\bigcap_{j \geq 1} A_j$ equal to $\{0\}$ or $\{\{0\}\}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am learning this [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_limit), which uses `sequence of sets` in the definition

> Suppose that ${\displaystyle \{A_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty }}$ is a sequence
>   of sets. The two equivalent definitions are as follows.
>
> Using union and intersection, define
>
> $\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} A_n = \bigcup_{n \ge 1} \bigcap_{j \geq n} A_j$
>
> ...
>
> The sequence ${A_n}$ is said to be nondecreasing if each $A_n ⊂
> A_{n+1}$

the simplest example of a (monotonic increasing) sequence I can imagine is the Natural number $\{0, 1, 2, …\}$

I assume this $\{\{0\}, \{0, 1\}, ..., \{0, 1, 2, …\}\}$ is an nondecreasing sequence of sets.

limit infimum is defined as

> $\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} A_n = \bigcup_{n \ge 1} \bigcap_{j \geq n} A_j$

to understand this easily, I would like to consider $\bigcap_{j \geq 1} A_j$ first

so, is $\bigcap_{j \geq 1} A_j$ equal to

$\{0\}$

or

$\{\{0\}\}$

I think it is the last one, and I need a double-check

Comment: You have a sequence $\{ A_n \}_n$ of sets, meaning that the $A_i$ are the elements of the sequence, that is itself a set. The intersection of all the sets of the sequence - if it is different from the empty set - will be the "smallest" set of the sequence, and thus will be an element of the sequence.

Comment: $\bigcap_{j\geq 1} A_j$ in this context is referring to $\{0\}\cap \{0,1\}\cap \{0,1,2\}\cap \cdots$ which will be $\{0\}$

Comment: Consider for simplicity the first two elements of the sequence : $\{ 0 \}$ and $\{ 0,1 \}$. The intersection of the two is the "usual" intersection, i.e. the set of the elements belonging to both : $\{ 0 \}$.

Comment: If $A_n=\{0,1,\dots,n\}$ then $$\bigcap_{i\geq n} A_i = A_n.$$ That's true for any monotonic increasing sequence of sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $$\bigcap _{j\ge 1} A_j =\{0\}$$ because the only member which is common to all $A_j$ is $0$

Note that $\{0\}$ is not a member of $A_j$ so it is not a member of the intersection.