# Given $\{A_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}=(\{1\},\{1,2\},...,\{1,2,…,n\})$, is $\bigcap_{j \geq 1} A_j$ equal to $\{1\}$ or $\{\{1\}\}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

this question is **different to** this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3310444/678038), which introduces $\{0\}$  (my own mistake) that is not a member of $A_j$, and someone had posted an answer based on that, so it is not appropriate to modify the whole which would disable that answer.

---

I am learning this [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_limit), which uses `sequence of sets` in the definition

> Suppose that ${\displaystyle \{A_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty }}$ is a sequence
>   of sets. The two equivalent definitions are as follows.
>
> Using union and intersection, define
>
> $\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} A_n = \bigcup_{n \ge 1} \bigcap_{j \geq n} A_j$
>
> ...
>
> The sequence ${A_n}$ is said to be nondecreasing if each $A_n ⊂
> A_{n+1}$

the simplest example of a (monotonic increasing) sequence I can imagine is the Natural number $(1, 2, … , n), \quad where \quad n \in \mathbb {N}^*$

I assume this $(\{1\},\{1,2\},...,\{1,2,…,n\}), \quad where \quad n \in \mathbb {N}^*$, is an nondecreasing sequence of sets.

to be clear, $A_1 = \{1\}, A_2 = \{1,2\}, ..., A_n = \{1,2,…,n\}$

limit infimum is defined as

> $\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} A_n = \bigcup_{n \ge 1} \bigcap_{j \geq n} A_j$

to understand this easily, I would like to consider $\bigcap_{j \geq 1} A_j$ first

so, is $\bigcap_{j \geq 1} A_j$ equal to

$\{\{1\}\}$

or

$\{1\}$

I think it is the last one, and I need a double-check

Comment: It is kind of confusing to write $\{A_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ as notation of a sequence of sets. One can interpreted that as the sequence $A_1,A_2,\dots$ but also as the sequence $\{A_1\},\{A_2\},\dots$. Which one do you mean? And secondly for certainty: do we have $A_n=\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ here?

Comment: @drhab I didn't mean that we have $A_n=\{1,2,\dots,n\}$, if there is any part of my OP misleading that, please point it out, thanks in advance.

Comment: Then how is $A_n$ defined in your question?

Comment: I agree with you about the confusing sequence notation, which has been buzzing me a lot. I am writing another post about that.

Comment: @drhab $A_1 = \{1\}, A_2 = \{1,2\}, ..., A_n = \{1,2,…,n\}$

Comment: So when you write $\{A_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$, you really mean $(A_n)_{n=1}^\infty$?

Comment: If you make it something like: "$A_1,A_2,\dots$ is a sequence of sets and $A_n=\{1,2,\dots,n\}$..." then everything is clear to everyone. Also you can use $(A_n)_n$ instead of $A_1,A_2,\dots$.

Comment: And when you write $(\{1\},\{1,2\},…,\{1,2,…,n\})$, you really mean $(\{1\},\{1,2\},…,\{1,2,…,n\},\ldots)$?

Comment: @TonyK Actually I am not sure if I should put ... at the end, would you please provide some solid reasons to do that on this thread 
[notation of a sequence of sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3310585/678038)

Comment: @drhab thanks man. Your notation is more clear. would you please mv that to the answer for this thread 
[notation of a sequence of sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3310585/678038)

Answer (score 1):

Here $A_n= \{\{1\}, \{1,2\},\ldots,\{1,\ldots,n\}\}$. All sets $A_n$ have the element $\{1\}$ in common. So the intersection $\bigcap_{n\geq 1} A_n$ consists of the set $\{\{1\}\}$.

Haha, sorry, but in your case $A_n=\{1,\ldots,n\}$, $n\geq 1$, the intersection is indeed $\{1\}$.

I hope this distinction helps.

Comment: I meant $A_1 = \{1\}, A_2 = \{1,2\}, ..., A_n = \{1,2,…,n\}$, my previous is not clear, sorry for that.